# Regex dynamic string manipulation

Tags: ruby, regex

Im aiming for a regex formula to return chunks of a string based on a character, if this string contains L1 then its going to be only one chunk, if L2 is found it would return 2 chunks, L3 = 3 chunks.

Example

Lets assume we have this string

```
"L2N1N1"
```

and we would like to get 2 string

```
"L2N1" and "L2N1N1"
```

Another example

```
"L3N1N1N2"
```

to return 3 strings

```
"L3N1" "L3N1N1" "L3N1N1N2"
```

Im using Ruby

Comment: Neither `["L3N1"]["L3N1N1"]` nor `["L3N1"]["L3N1N1"]["L3N1N1N2"]` are ruby objects you expect to receive. Please state properly what is the expected outcome.

Comment: @mudasobwa Im expecting strings and returning string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"L3N1N1N2".sub(/L(\d)(?:N\d)+/) do |m|
  $1.to_i.times.map { |i| m[0..3+2*i] }.join(' ')
end
#⇒ "L3N1 L3N1N1 L3N1N1N2"
```

Comment: Perfect its worked as expected, could you please remove the bracket at the very end though.

Comment: Ah, indeed, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Respect. Understanding the question was at least as hard as finding the answer.